# Change Windows 7 Explorer's Details Pane limits

Tags: windows-7, windows, statusbar

The status bar's functionality in Windows 7 (and maybe Vista, but I don't know for sure) is no longer showing me what it used to in previous Windows. I have tried all possible options such as Classic Shell and so on. Basically, the one thing I miss most is seeing at a glance the total size of my selected files.

I know I can press Alt+Enter or whatever, but that's not the point. The point is that the so-called 'details' pane stops providing details if more than 15 files are selected. Cannot understand the reason behind such a stupid arbitrary limit, that doesn't *seem* to be user-configurable at all.

Anyway, what I'm looking for is a way to change that limit, either via the registry or otherwise. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to change the arbitrarily low (and extremely silly) limit of 15 files imposed by Microsoft on the Details Pane in Windows 7. [**MultipleInvokePromptMinimum**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2022295) only changes the limits for the context menu.

Answer (score 3):

Put this in a text editor, save it as a .reg file, then apply it. this changes it from 15 to 256, but you can use whatever number you want.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Sets maximum files allowed to be opened concurrently to 256. (Default is 15.)
; Hexadecimal.
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]
"MultipleInvokePromptMinimum"=dword:00000100
```

Comment: This does not work on my machine, not even after reastarting explorer.exe or the machine itself.

Comment: @IstvánZachar, that’s because it only affects *running* more than 15 files, not showing information about more than 15 files as the OP was asking about. (I really don’t know what the heck the four people who up-voted this answer were thinking since it obviously doesn’t work. This is a good example of how meaningless votes are since people obviously do it randomly for whatever *looks* good.)

Comment: @Synetech it's not that easy. People (like me) who are looking for this code google `MultipleInvokePromptMinimum`, and find the code they are looking for, and thanks the guy, even if the answer is off topic. I thank you @gaff, but can't upvote unless you mention it as a side answer.